# Handling property does not exist when using JavaScript libraries in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm using TypeScript for a Vue.js app and I'm trying to use the drop event to trigger uploading an image like this:

```
handleDOMEvents: {
    drop(view, event) {
        const hasFiles = event.dataTransfer
            && event.dataTransfer.files
            && event.dataTransfer.files.length;
        if (hasFiles) {
            upload(event.dataTransfer.files);
        }
    }
}
```

(The full guide I'm follow is: https://gist.github.com/slava-vishnyakov/16076dff1a77ddaca93c4bccd4ec4521)

The code works, but TypeScript is giving a warning on the `.dataTransfer` lines:

> Property 'dataTransfer' does not exist on type 'Event'

The reason is that the `event` argument of the `drop` function is expecting an `Event` object, which doesn't have the `dataTransfer` property.

However, I would expect that `drop()` should always expect a `DragEvent`, but this is set in the external library so I don't have control over it.

How can I correctly handle this in TypeScript? Is is as simple as adding something like `if (typeof(event) !== DragEvent)`? Or is there a better way to get TypeScript to recognise this as a `DragEvent`? Is this just a case where it's best to ignore the warning?

I'm trying to understand what the best practice approach to handle this would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea with `if (typeof(event) !== DragEvent)`, except for the fact that TS types don't exist at runtime, so you can't check for them like that.

The way to do this is to create a custom [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) on the field `event.type`:

```
function isDragEvent(e: Event): e is DragEvent {
  return e.type === "drag";
}
```

You can then use it as a condition:

```
drop(view, event) {
    if(isDragEvent(event)){
        // TS recognizes that event is a DragEvent and has a dataTransfer member
        const hasFiles = event.dataTransfer
            && event.dataTransfer.files
            && event.dataTransfer.files.length;
        if (hasFiles) {
            upload(event.dataTransfer.files);
        }
    
    } else {
        throw new Error("the passed event is not a DragEvent")
    }
}
```